# QgsMapLayerRegistry().removeMapLayers(wfs_layer) causes crash

Tags: qgis, wfs

I have a WFS layer, served by Geoserver, loaded in QGIS using the standard 'Add WFS layer' dialog. When I try to remove it using:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry().instance().removeMapLayer(wfs_layer.id())
```

I get a full application crash, with no Python errors. This also happens when I use `wfs_layer.reload()` and `wfs_layer.dataProvider().reloadData()`. These methods previously worked on the same WFS layer. The service and content of the layer has not changed. The methods work when manipulating a (PostgreSQL) database layer.

I have made no changes to the code that I can see would affect the ability to reload data.

Any ideas or experiences?

Comment: I logged a bug here: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11062, it seems to be an issue with manipulating a cached WFS layer (i.e. a WFS layer without a 'bbox' parameter in the url)

Comment: Seems to be now fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry().instance().removeMapLayers(wfs_layer.id())
```

or

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry().instance().removeMapLayers([wfs_layer.id()])
```

instead? (Note the plural "s" at removeMapLayer**s**)
This worked for me.